# How can I tell what kind of JOBY tripod I own?

Tags: tripod, gorillapod

When I first bought my Canon EOS 7D at a local electronics dealer, I also bought a JOBY Gorillapod for it. I've hardly used it though, as my camera weighs a *ton* and the tripod nearly buckles under its weight. How can I tell what version of the tripod I got from looking at the tripod itself? All it has on it is the JOBY logo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the [Joby website](http://joby.com/gorillapod). They are all different!

Pay attention to the color of the joints and if yours has a joint above where the legs join or not. If there is a built-in head, look at it and compare as they are three distinct ones. It is not easy to see but the focus joints has rings which are metallic instead of grey.

The specs are available there too. If you want to really be sure, then you can weigh it.

Comment: Looks like I own the SLR one. I'll probably upgrade to the Focus edition, as I like my stands to be really stable :)

Comment: Then you might want to consider a real, non-Gorillapod, tripod. The GP's are great for what they do, but they are never going to be "really stable"